# How to specify proxy authentication credentials in Apache httpclient in addition to the target site credentials?

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to connect to a remote web site via proxy using Apache httpclient.
Both the proxy and the web site are using basic authentication with different logins/passwords. 
I have the below code that connects to the remote site via proxy. 
But I can't figure out how to add proxy credentials there. 
Any ideas?

```
...
    this.proxy = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(new HttpHost(host, port, scheme)).build();
    this.proxyEnabled = true;
...
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.username,
            this.password);

    if (debug) {
        credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
    } else {
        credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(this.getHost(), -1),
                creds);
    }

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();


    try {

        if (proxyEnabled) {
            httpRequest.setConfig(this.proxy);

        }

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpRequest);
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CredentialsProvider` may manage multiple `AuthScope`s, see e.g. the implementation in `BasicCredentialsProvider` (note the call to `credMap.put()`):

```
@Override
public void setCredentials(
        final AuthScope authscope,
        final Credentials credentials) {
    Args.notNull(authscope, "Authentication scope");
    credMap.put(authscope, credentials);
}
```

So just calling `setCredentials()` for each scope should work:

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

AuthScope siteScope = new AuthScope(siteHost, sitePort);
Credentials siteCreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(siteUsername, sitePassword);
credsProvider.setCredentials(siteScope, siteCreds);

AuthScope proxyScope = new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Credentials proxyCreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword);
credsProvider.setCredentials(proxyScope, proxyCreds);
```